# Error al actualizar campo en tabla con condicional en php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7, condiciones

Tengo una tabla de registros que contiene id, nombre, tipo y **activo**.
Desde un listado en html y php envío con un botón el id del registro a un archivo de modificación. Dicho archivo de modificación **recibe el id de la empresa** y decide entre dos posibles respuestas **Si lo actualiza a No** y si es **No lo actualiza a Si**, es simple pero **solo me actualiza de "Si a No" pero si quiero regresarlo de "No a Si" no lo hace**, creo que esta mal mi condición pero se cual sea.

```
<?php
$id_empresa = $_GET['id_empresa'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydbname"); 
$conn -> set_charset("utf8"); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM empresasregistradas";
$resultado = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
$row['id_empresa'];
if($row['activo'] ==='Si'){
    $activoNo = "No";
    $sentencia="UPDATE empresasregistradas SET activo='$activoNo' where 
   id_empresa ='$id_empresa'";
    $conn->query($sentencia)or die ("Error al actualizar 
   datos".mysqli_error($conn));

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          alert("Empresa Modificada Éxitosamente");
          window.location.href="admin.php";
           </script>';

}elseif($row['activo']==='No'){
    $activoSi = "Si";
    $sentencia="UPDATE empresasregistradas SET activo='$activoSi' where 
  id_empresa ='$id_empresa'";
    $conn->query($sentencia)or die ("Error al actualizar 
  datos".mysqli_error($conn));

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          alert("Empresa Modificada Éxitosamente");
          window.location.href="admin.php";
           </script>';

}else{
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
           alert("Error al modificar");
           window.location.href="admin.php";
         </script>';
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te muestra?

Comment: @RafaelBautistaMartinez en realidad me hace el cambio de "Si" a "No" pero no lo cambia de "No" a "Si".

Comment: Hola es simple estás asignando, no comparando `if($row['activo']='Si')` asigna si y se calcula como verdadero igualmente `if($row['activo']='No')` asigna no y se calcula como verdadero. debes hacer ** `if($row['activo']=='Si')` ** para que haya comparación y no asignación. Ten presente **== comparación débil, === comparación estricta**

Comment: @quevedo Si cambia la opción pero si quiero regresar a "Si" no lo hace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta en la declaración del `if`, estas usando `=` en ves de `==` y por ultimo estas olvidando el signo `$` para llamar variables.

- `$activo = 'Si'`  Es asignación ( retorna el string `Si`)
- `$activo == 'Si'` Es pregunta ( un operador lógico retorna `true` o `false`).

Ahora una posible solución es la siguiente, usando un operador ternario para cambiar el valor del estado del campo `activo` de la empresa.

```
$es_activo = "Si";

$estado = $row['activo']; // traigo el valor de campo activo

$nuevo_estado = $estado == $es_activo ? "No" : "Si";

$sentencia="UPDATE empresasregistradas SET activo='$nuevo_estado' where id ='$id'";
$conn->query($sentencia)or die ("Error al actualizar datos".mysqli_error($conn));
```

Una recomendación futura para evitar confusiones lógicas es que las variables que representan valores booleanos ya sea `true` 0 `false` o semanticamente `Si`,`No`,`Activo`,`Inactivo`..ect, las declaras anteponiendo `$is_` asi sabes que haces referencias a un valor que sera booleano.

Si no deseas usar el operador ternario,crear el `$nuevoEstado` dentro de tu `if/elseif` después declaras la `$sentencia`, ademas de usar la función `lowerCase()` para hacer que todo el texto sea minúscula evitando problemas de [Case Sensitivity](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensible_a_may%C3%BAsculas_y_min%C3%BAsculas)

```
$estado = $row['activo'];
$estadoNO = 'no';
$estadoSi = 'si';
$nuevoEstado = '';
if(strtolower($estado) == strtolower($estadoSi)){
  $nuevoEstado = $estadoNo;
} elseif(strtolower($estado) == strtolower($estadoSi)){
  $nuevoEstado = $estadoSi;
}

if($nuevoEstado != ''){
  $sentencia="UPDATE empresasregistradas SET activo='$nuevoEstado' where id_empresa ='$id_empresa'";
  $conn->query($sentencia)or die ("Error al actualizar datos".mysqli_error($conn));
  echo "Ok";
} else {
  echo "Erro";

}
```

Comment: Si cambia la opción pero si quiero regresar a "Si" no lo hace.

Comment: Actualiza tu nuevo código en la pregunta, para ver en donde esta cometiendo error.

Comment: gracias, ya realicé la actualización     SALUDOS

Comment: He actualizado el código agregando función `lowerCase` y limpiando un poco el código, dejando la declaración de `$sentecia` por fuera eso sera mas limpio y mas fácil de identificar el error.

Comment: agradezco tu ayuda. Me parece que la función que estamos buscando es `strtolower` ya que `lowerCase` me lo marca como `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function lowerCase()`

Comment: Me sigue haciendo la actualización a `no` pero si quiero regresar a `si` no lo hace y me manda enseguida al mensaje de error del `else`

Comment: Revisa si estas guardando la primera vez algun valor con espacio, ¿que tipo de datos es la columna? varchar, boolean ¿?

Comment: ese campo esta diseñado con atributo VARCHAR

Comment: listo amigo, solo corregí lo de lowerCase() por strtolower y funcionó¡

Comment: Agradezco tu apoyo